# How to create keyboard shortcuts for screen brightness in Xubuntu (XFCE Ubuntu)?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, xfce, xubuntu, brightness

How to create keyboard shortcuts for screen brightness in XFCE?

Ideally the solution uses inbuilt functionality which does not additionaly drain the battery (by installing a service/daemon, etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [xbacklight](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=xbacklight) to control the screen brightness. In XFCE, open the settings and add calls to `xbacklight` under “Keyboard” → “Application Shortcuts”: something like `xbacklight -dec 5 -steps 1` for <kbd>BrightnessDown</kbd> and `xbacklight -inc 5 -steps 1` for <kbd>BrightnessUp</kbd>.

A few graphics drivers don't support `xbacklight`. If it doesn't work on your system, you can ask about it on this site, mentioning your exact graphics card model.

A generic method that works with any desktop environment (or none at all) is to run [xbindkeys](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xbindkeys) (available in most distributions, including [Ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=xbindkeys)). Xbindkeys only consumes CPU when it starts up or when a key is pressed, and very little at that; it isn't a battery drain at all. (This would be the case for any remotely decent software providing the same functionality.) In `~/.xbindkeysrc`, put something like

```
"xbacklight -dec 5 -steps 1"
  XF86MonBrightnessDown
"xbacklight -inc 5 -steps 1"
  XF86MonBrightnessUp
```

and add `xbindkeys` to your startup applications in your desktop environment, or to `~/.xsession` or `~/.xinitrc` if you don't use a desktop environment.

Comment: The formatting is broken.

Answer (score 2):

## XFCE backlight buttons

First, install `xbacklight`

```
$ sudo apt install xbacklight
```

Then, check whether you have control over the backlight.

```
$ xbacklight -1
$ xbacklight +5
```

Should these commands result in a **`No outputs have backlight property`** error,
then [follow these remediating steps](https://askubuntu.com/a/1060843/164341) before proceeding.

Once `xbacklight -1` and `xbacklight +1` work from the command line, proceed with assigning these commands to respectively the `XF86MonBrightnessDown` and `XF86MonBrightnessUp` keys. This is done by hitting those keys when asked by the Settings → Keyboard → Application Shortcuts application.

Finally, **reboot** for these changes to take effect.

[image: Keyboard settings]